# blaming attitude members of the family saw

Tags: grammar

*Klara's child, born after they married, died in infancy. So did the next two. Klara's fourth child, Adolf, was her first to survive and he, too, seemed sickly. Alois vented his frustration on Klara, "So you have failed me once more! Is it impossible for you to bear me a healthy child?" **The words typify the hostile, blaming attitude members of the family saw.***

Source: Hitler: The Pathology of Evil by George Victor, p. 20. http://books.google.cz/books?id=JnB7cM1zUG4C&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false

I am a little bit puzzled over the emphasized part of the text above. Do I understand it properly and can I rewrite the part in this way: The words typify the hostile, blaming attitude in which Hitler's father saw the members of his family. If so, why is there such an odd word order?

Comment: I read it like this: *The words typify [the hostile, blaming attitude] (that) [members of the family] saw.*

Comment: @DamkerngT. has got it. In other words, Adolf's whole family was very familiar with how hostile Alois was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"*members of the family saw*" is a relative clause that modifies "*attitude*". This is much more obvious if we explicitly use "*that*" to mark the clause:

> The words typify the hostile, blaming attitude [that] members of the family saw.

We can rephrase the sentence like this:

> Members of the family saw a hostile, blaming attitude. The words typify that attitude.